# What is the fastest ways to divide and append into two variables from list of tuple (response from sqlalchemy) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

This is my first question here and if this is a dumb question, I'm sorry.

I have rows(around 1-2m) like below as sqlalchemy response.

```
rows = (
    ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 1, 2, 1, 2, 1000, 200, 300, 400, 200, 200),
    ('eee', 'fff', 'ggg', 'hhh', 1, 1, 3, 3, 900, 400, 100, 100, 100, 1000),
    ...
)
```

and I want to reformat as below.

```
a = (('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 1, 2, 1, 2),('eee', 'fff', 'ggg', 'hhh', 1, 1, 3, 3), ...)
b = ((1, 2, 1, 2, 1000, 200, 300, 400, 200, 200), (1, 1, 3, 3, 900, 400, 100, 100, 100, 1000), ...)
```

I came up with this code and it will take 6~7 seconds with 1.2m rows.

```
a = []
b = []
for r in rows:
    a.append(r[:8])
    b.append(r[4:])
```

Two list comprehensions are slower than above. by 1~2 seconds

```
a = set(r[:8] for r in rows)
b = tuple(r[4:] for r in rows)
```

Is this normal speed or too slow in python?
any solutions to speed this up?

Comment: does your benchmark include time to fetch from db?

Comment: How do you consume `a` and `b`?

Comment: Simultaneously? One after the other? You need indexed access in both?